# Thread 1: Simultaneous accesses to 0x104344480 SwiftUI IOS17

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, ios17

after updating to iOS 17 I encountered this error, there are no errors in the simulator and on a phone with iOS 16, on a phone with iOS 17 it constantly crashes when going through several views, here is an example of how I use the transition to going back through several views:

```
struct MainMenuView: View {
    @ObservedObject var navigationState: NavigationState
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {               
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        if appSettings.resumeGame {
                            isShowingDisableModal = true
                        } else {
                            appSettings.resetGame()
                            navigationState.teamBuildingView = true
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text(LocalizedStringKey("New Game"))
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(StartGameButtonStyle())
                    .disabled(isShowingDisableModal)
                    
                    if appSettings.resumeGame {
                        Button {
                            navigationState.continueScoreView = true
                        } label: {
                            Text(LocalizedStringKey("Continue"))
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(GameButtonStyle())
                        .disabled(isShowingDisableModal)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    CustomNavigationButton(action: {
                        navigationState.settingsView = true
                    }, imageName: "gearshape")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .opacity(isShowingDisableModal ? 0.5 : 1.0)
                    .disabled(isShowingDisableModal)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $navigationState.settingsView) {
                SettingsView()
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $navigationState.teamBuildingView) {
                TeamBuildingView(navigationState: navigationState)
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $navigationState.continueScoreView) {
                TeamScoreView(navigationState: navigationState)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that I go through two views, and try from 4 views to return to the first

```
struct TeamScoreView: View {    
    @ObservedObject var navigationState: NavigationState
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
          // SOME CODE
        }
        .navigationTitle(LocalizedStringKey("Team Scores"))
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                CustomNavigationButton(action: {
                    appSettings.resumeGame = true
                    navigationState.teamBuildingView = false
                    navigationState.continueScoreView = false
                }, imageName: "chevron.left")
                .opacity(appSettings.isGameOver ? 0 : 1)
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $navigationState.startGameView) {
            StartGameView(navigationState: navigationState)
        }
    }
```

and here when I try to go back I get this error, there are also places further where I use a similar return after several views and everything crashes with the same error.

**Може хтось з України може мені допомогти, або дати фітбек через діскорд чи якийсь відео зв'язок, напишіть мені, буду дуже вдячний**

Comment: Without a [mre], this isn't possible to debug

Comment: Hi, I bet the issue is in the .toolbar. I am facing the same crash when using it. Additionally, here's another crash report that appears to be the same: [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/738362). I am still digging into it, no workaround so far.

Comment: By the way, I've prepared a demo to reproduce the crash. I don't know how to attach it directly, so here's a dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/s4x49bykhjrnh7yxybajn/swiftui_toolbar_crash_example.zip?rlkey=d6iquywpvb8y3j0sshj6kjvh3&dl=0). You should press: "Click Me", then again "Click me" and then "Reset".

Comment: Further down the menu, this error triggers when I click on a button with approximate conditions for returning through one view (Not the toolbar), so I suspect that it’s a navigation stack, but I don’t know any other way to return through several views. Does the navigation stack under the hood work like an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from my answer in Apple forum,

I have provided a workaround, the drawback is basically there is a ~500ms delay on the toolbar appearance when you navigate back. Please use the default `.toolbar` for most parent views (The view that `NavigationStack` wraps) and then use `.safeToolbar` for all child screens.

```
// MARK: - safeToolbar
extension View {
    /// Adds a safe toolbar to the view with custom content.
    ///
    /// Use this modifier to safely apply a toolbar to the view. 
    /// This modifier is designed to handle potential crashes that may occur with the standard `toolbar` modifier on iOS 17.
    ///
    /// - Parameter content: A closure returning the custom content of the toolbar.
    /// - Returns: A modified view with the safe toolbar applied.
    /// - Note: This modifier automatically manages the presentation of the toolbar to prevent potential crashes on iOS 17.
    @ViewBuilder
    public func safeToolbar<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            modifier(SafeToolbarView(content))
        } else {
            toolbar(content: content)
        }
    }

    /// Adds a safe toolbar to the view with custom content.
    ///
    /// Use this modifier to safely apply a toolbar to the view. 
    /// This modifier is designed to handle potential crashes that may occur with the standard `toolbar` modifier on iOS 17.
    ///
    /// - Parameter content: A closure returning the custom content of the toolbar.
    /// - Returns: A modified view with the safe toolbar applied.
    /// - Note: This modifier automatically manages the presentation of the toolbar to prevent potential crashes on iOS 17.
    @ViewBuilder
    public func safeToolbar<Content: ToolbarContent>(@ToolbarContentBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            modifier(SafeToolbarContent(content))
        } else {
            toolbar(content: content)
        }
    }
}

private struct SafeToolbarView<ToolbarContent: View>: ViewModifier {
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = true
    private let toolBarContent: () -> ToolbarContent
    init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> ToolbarContent) {
        self.toolBarContent = content
    }
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear { isPresented = true }
            .onDisappear { isPresented = false }
            .toolbar(content: { if isPresented { toolBarContent() } })
    }
}

private struct SafeToolbarContent<S: ToolbarContent>: ViewModifier {
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = true
    private let toolBarContent: () -> S
    init(@ToolbarContentBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> S) {
        self.toolBarContent = content
    }
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear { isPresented = true }
            .onDisappear { isPresented = false }
            .toolbar(content: { if isPresented { toolBarContent() } })
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import SwiftUI

/// SwiftUI Toolbar crasher
/// =======================
///
/// Steps to reproduce
/// ------------------
/// * launch this app on a physical device running iOS 17 (any stable or beta release).
/// * Tap the center button ("Go to view 2")
/// * Tap the center button ("Go to view 3")
/// * Tap the center button ("Go to view 4")
/// * Tap the center button ("Go to view 5")
/// * Tap the center button ("Pop to root ")
///
/// Expected result
/// ---------------
/// * The app navigates back to the root screen.
///
/// Actual result
/// -------------
/// * The app crashes in 30-50% of the attempts.
///
///
class ToolbarCrasher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var navTree: NavigationTree? = nil
}

enum NavigationTree {
    case one(One?)
    var one: One? {
        switch self {
        case let .one(one): one
        }
    }
    var isOne: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .one: true
        }
    }
    enum One {
        case two(Two?)
        var two: Two? {
            switch self {
            case let .two(two): two
            }
        }
        var isTwo: Bool {
            switch self {
            case .two: true
            }
        }
        enum Two {
            case three(Three?)
            var three: Three? {
                switch self {
                case let .three(three): three
                }
            }
            var isThree: Bool {
                switch self {
                case .three: true
                }
            }
            enum Three {
                case four
                var isFour: Bool {
                    switch self {
                    case .four: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var toolbarCrasher: ToolbarCrasher = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Root View")
                Button(
                    action: { toolbarCrasher.navTree = .one(nil) },
                    label: { Text("Go to view 2") }
                )
            }
            .navigationDestination(
                isPresented: .init(
                    get: { toolbarCrasher.navTree?.isOne ?? false },
                    set: { isForward in if isForward { toolbarCrasher.navTree = nil } }
                ),
                destination: {
                    ContentView2(toolbarCrasher: toolbarCrasher)
                }
            )
            .padding()
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing, content: {
                    Button(
                        action: { toolbarCrasher.navTree = nil },
                        label: { Text("Pop to root ") }
                    )
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var toolbarCrasher: ToolbarCrasher
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 2")
            Button(
                action: { toolbarCrasher.navTree = .one(.two(nil)) },
                label: { Text("Go to view 3") }
            )
        }
        .safeToolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing, content: {
                Button(
                    action: { toolbarCrasher.navTree = nil },
                    label: { Text("Pop to root ") }
                )
            })
        }
        .navigationDestination(
            isPresented: .init(
                get: { toolbarCrasher.navTree?.one?.isTwo ?? false },
                set: { isForward in if isForward { toolbarCrasher.navTree = .one(nil) } }
            ),
            destination: {
                ContentView3(toolbarCrasher: toolbarCrasher)
            }
        )
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView3: View {
    @ObservedObject var toolbarCrasher: ToolbarCrasher
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 3")
            Button(
                action: { toolbarCrasher.navTree = .one(.two(.three(nil))) },
                label: { Text("Go to view 4") }
            )
        }
        .safeToolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing, content: {
                Button(
                    action: { toolbarCrasher.navTree = nil },
                    label: { Text("Pop to root ") }
                )
            })
        }
        .navigationDestination(
            isPresented: .init(
                get: { toolbarCrasher.navTree?.one?.two?.isThree ?? false },
                set: { isForward in if isForward { toolbarCrasher.navTree = .one(.two(nil)) } }
            ),
            destination: {
                ContentView4(state: toolbarCrasher)
            }
        )
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView4: View {
    @ObservedObject var state: ToolbarCrasher
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 4")
            Button(
                action: { state.navTree = .one(.two(.three(.four))) },
                label: { Text("Go to view 5") }
            )
        }
        .safeToolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing, content: {
                Button(
                    action: { state.navTree = nil },
                    label: { Text("Pop to root ") }
                )
            })
        }
        .navigationDestination(
            isPresented: .init(
                get: { state.navTree?.one?.two?.three?.isFour ?? false },
                set: { isForward in if isForward { state.navTree = .one(.two(.three(nil))) } }
            ),
            destination: {
                ContentView5(toolbarCrasher: state)
            }
        )
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView5: View {
    @ObservedObject var toolbarCrasher: ToolbarCrasher
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 5")
        Button(
            action: { toolbarCrasher.navTree = nil },
            label: { Text("Pop to root ") }
        )
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try and let you know if it worked, I hope this solves my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn’t help me, maybe the reason is something else, I hope I’ll figure it out over time, for now I’m a beginner and I can’t cope with this problem until someone helps me by looking at my code in full)

Comment: I'm sorry, this actually helped me, the problem turned out to be only in the toolbars, I left the navigation tree the same and did not use your option. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: At first I deleted only the problematic toolbar, but then I realized that I needed to completely remove all toolbars from my application in order to understand what the problem was.